# Get a filtered list from a terraform map of objects?

Tags: dictionary, object, terraform, local, hcl

I have a list of users with characteristics like this and I want to create a local variable that includes the names of the users in the "maker" group.

```
variable "users" {
  type = map(object({
    groups         = list(string)
  }))

  default = {
    "kevin.mccallister" = {
       groups = ["kids", "maker"],
    },
    "biff" = {
       groups = ["kids", "teens", "bully"],
    },
  }
}
```

I want to write the local like this, but it complains

> Error: Invalid 'for' expression ... Key expression is required when
> building an object.

```
locals {
  makers_list = flatten({
    for user, attr in var.users: user
    if contains(attr.groups, "makers")
  })
}
```

How can I take that map of objects and get out a list of names based on group affiliation?

Answer (score 0):

`flatten()` is not required for this. Also, the `{}` is pushing this to build an object. You can instead build a list using `[]` and then it will create a list of the users filtered by their group association.

```
makers_list = [
  for user, attr in var.users: user
    if contains(attr.groups, "makers")
]
```